# What are the differences between group and layer in KineticJs

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

I am developing a HTML5 web application using KineticJS. I read that in KineticJS there are grouping and layering. As far as I know there are no differences between them. Can you tell me the differences?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**The basic difference: Groups are containers while Layers are separators.**

Group:

- A group is a container for shaped objects inside a layer.
- For example, a group might contain both a circle and a rectangle.
- A group can be manipulated and all elements within that group are similarly manipulated.
- For example, dragging a group will simultaneously drag a circle and rectangle contained in that group.

Layer:

- Layers are actually separate canvas elements that are stacked atop each other.
- This is similar to the way layers work in Photoshop and Illustrator.
- Multiple layers are visible simultaneously.
- If objects from different layers overlap, the topmost object displays fully (like z-indexing).

Groups are used to contain multiple items so they can be manipulated as a group--like putting circles and lines into a group to create a "stickman".  Moving the group will move all the pieces of the stickman.

Layers are used to separate different items--like having a background layer that doesn't change and a top layer where animation is occurring.

Comment: It may also useful to reference the node hierarchy for the structure of Layers and groups from the GitHub Readme: https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/wiki It's also worth noting this quote: "Each layer has two canvas renderers, a scene renderer and a hit graph renderer." Performance wise, it would most likely be smart to group items together as much as possible that makes sense. And keep layers to a minimum, making separate layers only when it make sense to have another layer, like your examples above.

Answer (score 0):

Groups are simply group of elements or objects can be stacked in any way normally **within a layer**.

Layers are different Canvas area that can be added on the stage stacked over each other.

Comment: Your last statement is incorrect. A layer does not have to take up the entire stage, therefore you CAN display multiple layers at once. In fact, in KineticJS layers AND groups are transparent and cannot have the 'fill' property. This means that all layers and groups are visible and see through at all times, as long as they are in the viewport (canvas/stage) and they are not covered by the shapes contained within them. This is also noted in @markE's answer, which is the more correct and informative answer.