# HTML5 Canvas & KineticJS layer order switches on refresh

Tags: html5-canvas, kineticjs

I am building an animation with HTML5 Canvas and KineticJS. The animation works just fine. However, I've noticed that sometimes on refresh, the layer order of the images I am animating gets rearranged. This switch in layer order seems to happen at random. For instance, I can click refresh 5 times and the layer order is fine... click refresh another 3 times and the layer order rearranges. Can anyone help as to why this random switch in layer order occurs?

Comment: Are you refreshing before all animations are complete?

Comment: To be able to help you further you need to show us some code or more preferably a jsfiddle that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @projeqht Here is a fiddle of the animation http://jsfiddle.net/BYknR/3/

Comment: @markE I would only refresh after the animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your problem right here:

```
mac3rdpieceImageObj.onload = function () {
    // add the kinetic image to the layer
    mac3rdpieceLayer.add(mac3rdpiece);
    // add the layer to the stage
    myAnimateStage.add(mac3rdpieceLayer);
};

mac2ndpieceImageObj.onload = function () {
    // add the kinetic image to the layer
    mac2ndpieceLayer.add(mac2ndpiece);
    // add the layer to the stage
    myAnimateStage.add(mac2ndpieceLayer);
};

mac1stpieceImageObj.onload = function () {
    // add the kinetic image to the layer
    mac1stpieceLayer.add(mac1stpiece);
    // add the layer to the stage
    myAnimateStage.add(mac1stpieceLayer);
};
```

If you disable your browser cache, the problem will occur more often. Using these 3 onload functions, you have no way of controlling which image loads first. Chances are they'll load in order, but sometimes they won't. Whichever order they load in, that `layer` will be added first, and so sometimes they are out of order.

If you **must** use 3 different layers for your 3 images, you can fix this issue by **adding** the layers in order OUTSIDE of the `onload` functions:

```
myAnimateStage.add(mac3rdpieceLayer); //Add this layer to the stage first,
myAnimateStage.add(mac2ndpieceLayer); //Then this layer.
myAnimateStage.add(mac1stpieceLayer); //Then this layer. This is the top layer because it was added last.

mac3rdpieceImageObj.onload = function () {
    mac3rdpieceLayer.add(mac3rdpiece);
    mac3rdpieceLayer.draw();
};

mac2ndpieceImageObj.onload = function () {
    mac2ndpieceLayer.add(mac2ndpiece);    
    mac2ndpieceLayer.draw();
};

mac1stpieceImageObj.onload = function () {
    mac1stpieceLayer.add(mac1stpiece);    
    mac1stpieceLayer.draw();
};
```

This **guarantees** the order that the layers are added in.

You also need to use the `draw()` function on each layer after the image loads, so that you can see the image on the canvas. Here's the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/yC25a/)

**Suggestion:**

Instead of using 3 layers for your 3 images, use **1 Layer and 3 Groups** with each **Group** containing **1 image** (and anything else you need to add within each Group). Like this:

```
var macLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
myAnimateStage.add(macLayer);

var mac1stpieceGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
  //I suggest moving each image's (x,y) coordinates inside their group
});
var mac2ndpieceGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
  //And using x:0, y:0 for the actual image coordinates
});
var mac3rdpieceGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
  //That way the group holds the position, and you only have to manage one coordinate per group/image
});

macLayer.add(mac3rdpieceGroup); //Here's the order of your groups
macLayer.add(mac2ndpieceGroup);
macLayer.add(mac1stpieceGroup);

mac3rdpieceImageObj.onload = function () {
    mac3rdpieceGroup.add(mac3rdpiece);
    macLayer.draw();
};

mac2ndpieceImageObj.onload = function () {
    mac2ndpieceGroup.add(mac2ndpiece);    
    macLayer.draw();
};

mac1stpieceImageObj.onload = function () {
    mac1stpieceGroup.add(mac1stpiece);    
    macLayer.draw();
};
```

See this question for more information: [What are the differences between group and layer in KineticJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632068/what-are-the-differences-between-group-and-layer-in-kineticjs)

**Final Note:**

As a last alternative, you could probably also use the **`zIndex`** property to order which layer (or **group**!) should appear on top of the others. [Kinetic.Container#setZIndex](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Container.html#setZIndex)