# KineticJS Image and Rect Not Layering Correctly

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

Ok, so I am new to KineticJS and while playing with it, I can't seem to combine an image background with a rectangle layered above that image. Now, if I remove the background image, then the rectangle shows. Even if I put the rectangle code above the image, still doesn't show on top. Sure it is something simple I am missing but I can't seem to figure out what it is and can't find a similar issue here on stackoverflow. Thanks for the help.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>

    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.5.4.min.js"></script>
    <script defer="defer">
        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
            container: 'container',
            width: 600,
            height: 450
        });

        //Layer for our background
        var background_layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

        //Canvas background image
        var canvasBackgroundImage = new Image();
        canvasBackgroundImage.onload = function() {
            var backgroundImage = new Kinetic.Image({
                x: 0,
                y: 0,
                image: canvasBackgroundImage,
                width: 600,
                height: 450
            });

            background_layer.add(backgroundImage);
            stage.add(background_layer);
        };
        canvasBackgroundImage.src = 'images/quiz_back.jpg'; //Location of our background

        //Question container
        var question_container_layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
        var question_container = new Kinetic.Rect({
            x: 100,
            y: 100,
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            fill: 'green',
            stroke: 'black',
            strokeWidth: 2
        });
        question_container_layer.add(question_container);
        stage.add(question_container_layer);

    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're adding `background_layer` to the stage inside the `canvasBackgroundImage.onload` function. Javascript will run through the entire script, and add the `question_container_layer` to the stage first, AND THEN when your image loads, the `background_layer` will be added to the stage. As a result, the background image always appears on top of your rectangle layer.

To fix this, add the layers to your stage outside of your `onload` function:

```
<script defer="defer">
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 600,
        height: 450
    });

    //Layer for our background
    var background_layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    var question_container_layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(background_layer);
    stage.add(question_container_layer);

    //Canvas background image
    var canvasBackgroundImage = new Image();
    canvasBackgroundImage.onload = function() {
        var backgroundImage = new Kinetic.Image({
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            image: canvasBackgroundImage,
            width: 600,
            height: 450
        });
        background_layer.add(backgroundImage);
        background_layer.draw();
    };
    canvasBackgroundImage.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg'; //Location of our background

    //Question container

    var question_container = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: 50,
        y: 50,
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        fill: 'green',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 2
    });
    question_container_layer.add(question_container);

    question_container_layer.draw();

</script>
```

To avoid this in the future, unless you have dynamic layers to be added to the stage, I would recommend adding all known layers to the stage before doing anything else. That way you can control the ordering of your layers.

Or alternatively, you can use the `zIndex` property to order your layers. See here: [Kinetic.Container#setZIndex](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Container.html#setZIndex)

Comment: Also, see this question for a similar scenario... and also for some more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659049/html5-canvas-kineticjs-layer-order-switches-on-refresh/

Comment: Thanks, I did figure out the setZIndex option shortly after you posted about it. That did fix the issue.