# Kineticjs stops rendering

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

Using kinetic js for a searchable directory listing on a kiosk.  It works great!! except for one issue.  I am in chrome and have an a,b,c,d etc list on the side a user can click for names starting with that letter.  When a letter is clicked, it re-renders the whole stage.  After 10-15 times of doing that, the stage comes up blank, but I can still click where a name would be and get its detail "lightbox" or click where a letter would be and get a new listing, but still a blank stage, ie no fill or color on any rects or text.  Whats worse is that if I go to an entirely different kiosk page that uses KineticJS for something else, it does not render either and never will again unless I leave the domain (localhost) and go to google or something and come back, or open a new tab or restart Chrome.  I am totally lost now and redoing it without Kinetic is going to be a huge loss if I can't figure this out.

I have gone through and tried to be sure my memory management was ok and pretty sure it is.  My system memory does grow, but Chrome seems to gargbage collect it fairly quickly.  I have even tried calling destroy() on every kineticjs object I create when re-rendering with no luck.

Comment: Does the entire stage need to be re-rendered? Can you just re-render the layers, or have each list as a separate layer/group and hide/show them as needed? We'll need to see some code (and a jsfiddle would be nice) to help further..

Comment: I probably don't HAVE to re-render the whole stage, but it was a simple solution and it works beautifully smooth.  My script is 800+ lines with all the needed functionality (search, popup keyboard (also kineticjs) sorting etc).  I'll try to recreate in a jsfiddle and post it ASAP.

Comment: So NOT re rendering the stage seemed to take care of it.  It was an easy change to make, but now it seems to hog memory up more.  I'll take a look at the docs to make sure I am reusing it right.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I am still wondering why it would lock it up between entirely different pages on the same site though?

Comment: How are you re-rendering the stage by the way, stage.draw()?

Comment: Yes, what I have now is when I call my function to re-render, I do stage.destroyChildren(), add my new layers and then stage.draw().  Still looking to see what all should be done to reuse the stage and reclaim the memory.

Comment: Like I mentioned earlier, is it necessary to destroy the stage every time you want to add your new layers? I would think it'd be more efficient to add all your layers to the stage **once**, hide the ones that inactive, and when you need to switch, just show/hide the layers accordingly. It sounds expensive to keep destroying/readding everything. Another way to improve performance is to group the objects by Groups instead of Layers, if that makes sense. Each layer initiates 2 canvases so you can see why it would be more expensive.

Comment: More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632068/what-are-the-differences-between-group-and-layer-in-kineticjs/17632137#comment25677607_17632137

Comment: I am now re using the 1 stage object with much improvement.  I did also try to draw all 26 (letters of the alphabet) layers and show/hide them, but it is also very expensive.  A user can also pull up a mobile like keypad and search for a name and matches will show on the same stage.  I am pulling data for this directory from Active Directory (backend is a Django server and a service that posts from AD nightly) and there are nearly 1000 entries to manage.  I saw no difference in responsiveness using it like that, but significantly more load time impacting usability.  It is now working very well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a known issue in Chrome 29 in regards to canvas rendering. The issue is not present in version 28 or 30. Join the party and help draw eyes to the issue. :) https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=280153&thanks=280153&ts=1377616231#makechanges

As a temp workaround you can turn off the 2d canvas acceleration by setting 'Disable accelerated 2D canvas' flag to enable.

Comment: Dude!!  I can't tell you how long I've been fighting with this.  It almost flopped my whole project.  Disabling the 2d canvas on 29 and also moving to 30 both took care of it.  Oh well, my javascript is now absolutely bulletproof at least!!!  Thanks much!!

Comment: Glad I could help! I was pulling my hair out for a bit as well.

Comment: thanks, works great!  now, how do I get all of my end users to do this?