# KineticJS Setting a Variable Value On an Event

Tags: javascript, dom-events, kineticjs

I define several kineticJS circles in an object and create and display several of those objects. What I want is to generate an XML object based on the ones the user selects out of the displayed circles.

For this I tried to set a variable value defined in the object when clicked on a particular circle and call it by an `object.property` kind of a way. However, this doesn't work.

Following is some of the code I used for the job:

```
    function Graph(i, j, refRel, refRelTxt) {

        subNodes = seventeen + eighteen + nineteen;
        graphNode = "<" + refRelTxt + ">" + subNodes + "<" + refRelTxt + ">";


        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer({
            width: 200,
            height: 100,
            x: (stage.getWidth() / 2.5) + i,
            y: (stage.getHeight() / 2.5) + j

        });


        var circle19 = new Kinetic.Circle({
            x: 10,
            y: layer.getHeight() / 2,
            radius: cradius,
            fill: '#CCCCCC'
        });

        //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++     

        var circle18 = new Kinetic.Circle({
            x: 10 + n,
            y: (layer.getHeight() / 2) - m,
            radius: cradius,
            fill: '#CCCCCC'
        });

        var circle17 = new Kinetic.Circle({
            x: 10 + n,
            y: (layer.getHeight() / 2) + m,
            radius: cradius,
            fill: '#CCCCCC'
        });


        //============Mouse in/out operations


        circle17.on('click', function (evt) {
            this.setFill('#00FF00');
            layer.draw();
            seventeen = "<node>seventeen<node>";
        });

        circle18.on('click', function (evt) {
            this.setFill('#00FF00');
            layer.draw();
            eighteen = "<node>eighteen<node>";
        });

        circle19.on('click', function (evt) {
            this.setFill('#00FF00');
            layer.draw();
            nineteen = "<node>nineteen<node>";;
        });


        // add the shape to the layer
        layer.add(circle19);
        layer.add(circle18);
        layer.add(circle17);

        stage.add(layer);
    }
```

Create some graph objects like the following:

```
    var graph19 = new Graph(-(4*hdist), (0*vdist),"circle19","nineteen");
```

And then call the `graph19.graphNode` value to get the xml out based on the circles the user has clicked.  However, `graph19.graphNode` doesn't get set with the values dynamically. I know I am doing something wrong here that I cannot figure out. When I set global variables and do this it works. What I want is to extract the xmls form the various Graph objects that are created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly... you want to be able to call `graph19.graphNode` and it will output some pre-defined xml string that is *dynamically* populated depending on which circles the user clicked.

If so:

First off, to be able to call the property `graphNode` from a `new Graph` object, you have to assign **`this.graphNode`** instead of just `graphNode` by itself. Otherwise when you call `graph19.graphNode` it will be `undefined`.

Then you need to assign `this` to a variable like: `var node = this;` so that you can access `node` within the click function. (This is because by default, when you use `this` inside a Kinetic event function, *click* in this case, `this` will be assigned to the `Kinetic.Shape` you are binding the event to)

Finally, you need to update `node` (**this.graphNode**) every time you click a circle, use an array to keep track of the elements selected:

```
    this.graphNode = '';
    var node = this;
    var nodeText = '';

    circle17.on('click', function (evt) {
        this.setFill('#00FF00');
        layer.draw();
        seventeen = "<node>seventeen<node>";
        nodeText += seventeen;
        node.graphNode = "<" + refRelTxt + ">" + nodeText + "<" + refRelTxt + ">";
    });

    circle18.on('click', function (evt) {
        this.setFill('#00FF00');
        layer.draw();
        eighteen = "<node>eighteen<node>";
        nodeText += eighteen;
        node.graphNode = "<" + refRelTxt + ">" + nodeText + "<" + refRelTxt + ">";
    });

    circle19.on('click', function (evt) {
        this.setFill('#00FF00');
        layer.draw();
        nineteen = "<node>nineteen<node>";
        nodeText += nineteen;
        node.graphNode = "<" + refRelTxt + ">" + nodeText + "<" + refRelTxt + ">";
    });
```

The reason your code wasn't working was because you've defined

`subNodes = seventeen + eighteen + nineteen;`

Before `seventeen` `eighteen` and `nineteen` have even been defined (since they are defined when the user clicks on the the respective `Kinetic.Circle`

Also, **as a suggestion** I recommend that instead of creating a new `Kinetic.Layer` and adding it to the `stage` every time you call your `Graph` function, you might want to create a new `Kinetic.Group` instead and add that to the `layer`. See here for more information: [What are the differences between group and layer in KineticJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632068/what-are-the-differences-between-group-and-layer-in-kineticjs)

**UPDATE**

Okay if you need to deselect the objects as well, we'll need to keep track of which objects are selected in an array. Then we can use that array to determine how `this.graphNode` will be populated.

Something like this (note I haven't tested this code..):

```
    this.graphNode = '';
    this.selectedNodes = [];
    this.nodeText = '';
    var node = this;

    circle17.on('click', function (evt) {
        this.setFill('#00FF00');
        layer.draw();
        seventeen = "<node>seventeen<node>";
        selectedNodes.push(seventeen);
        node.nodeText = '';
        for (var i=0; i<selectedNodes.length; i++) {
          node.nodeText += selectedNodes[i];
        }
        node.graphNode = "<" + refRelTxt + ">" + node.nodeText + "<" + refRelTxt + ">";
    });

    circle18.on('click', function (evt) {
        this.setFill('#00FF00');
        layer.draw();
        eighteen = "<node>eighteen<node>";
        selectedNodes.push(eighteen);
        node.nodeText = '';
        for (var i=0; i<selectedNodes.length; i++) {
          node.nodeText += selectedNodes[i];
        }
        node.graphNode = "<" + refRelTxt + ">" + node.nodeText + "<" + refRelTxt + ">";
    });

    circle19.on('click', function (evt) {
        this.setFill('#00FF00');
        layer.draw();
        nineteen = "<node>nineteen<node>";
        selectedNodes.push(nineteen);
        node.nodeText = '';
        for (var i=0; i<selectedNodes.length; i++) {
          node.nodeText += selectedNodes[i];
        }
        node.graphNode = "<" + refRelTxt + ">" + node.nodeText + "<" + refRelTxt + ">";
    });
```

After this you can do something similar to remove the object from the `selectedNodes` array on `dblclick` event.

Comment: Hi thanks for your detailed answer. Actually I want to make the user available, on double click to deselect the selected layer and remove the assigned xml tag. For this I wanted each circle to be associated with a object to store its own xml value and later on use all these small tags in the objects to create a higher level xml node. In that case if the user selects a circle the xml tag is assigned to the object and if deselected the object is left with a blank string. Do you think I could do this with your suggestion?

Comment: Thank you very much. Your suggestions work like a charm. My issues were more js than kineticjs. Do you recommend any source to get a strong knowledge about js? (as you could see some fundamental concepts are missing)